# Canon MF8280Cw Multi-purpose tray error

Tags: canon

I've been using this MF8280Cw with Zorin OS and it's worked fine.  Now I get an error that there is no paper in the multi-purpose tray.  I've never used this tray and don't want to.  I just want to print from the main paper tray.  I've updated the firmware.  I've turned off that tray in the web based settings.  I don't have this problem running Windows 7.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ZorinOS is off-topic here. You're welcome to post at Unix & Linux.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu LTS on another computer and have the exact same problem.  I have multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of your valuable help, I have fixed the problem.  Canon lists a linux driver on it's support site in Malaysia.  It's in English for those concerned.  Here's the link.

[Linux driver for Canon MF8280Cw](https://my.canon/en/support/imageCLASS%20MF8280Cw/model)